# CS1061: (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error:

> CS1061:'ASP.dashboard_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button6_Click' and no extension method 'Button6_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.dashboard_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I run it on my development PC it works fine, however when I uploaded on the server it gives this error.

Source Error:

```
Line 252:
Line 253:                </td><td>
Line 254:<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" BackColor="#FF9933"     ForeColor="White"   Height="30px" Text="Search" Width="129px" OnClick="Button3_Click" Visible="False" />
Line 255:                </td>
Line 256:            </tr>
```

My CS file :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" BackColor="#FF9933" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" Height="30px" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="Search" Visible="False" Width="200px" />
```

Code Behind :

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from AssignedProject  where under=@Projectid", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projectid", DropDownList2.Text);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Label16.Text = "View FTEs Details";
            GridView5.Visible = true;
            GridView2.Visible = false;
            GridView5.DataSource = dt;
            GridView5.DataBind();
          
        }
        else
        {
            Label16.Text = " On Going Project";
            loadGV();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

I have tried to:

1. Clean and Rebuild
2. Recreate the button and event
3. Researched and they said to add Inherit tag at `<@Page`; it's already there.

Nothing seems to be working. It confuses me as it was running a day before on the server too. Just added this button and dropdownlist since then its not working.

Comment: Your onclick function name are not a match

Comment: 'Button6_Click' ??? where is it in code behind ?

Comment: Sorry error was of before and made changes was not able to refresh it, Edited

Comment: Please update all text that is incorrect. What is the error after the changes you made. What is the name of your class. Can you show more of your html and cs file? What web server are you running on your developer machine and what do you use on your server?

Answer (score 1):

At Line Number 1061. You have another Button with Onclick="Button6_Click" and Protected void 'Button6_Click'  is deleted from code behind.

Debugger not necessary point at exact error location.

Comment: I dont see any Button6 anywhere ?

Comment: Check your dashboard_aspx <its Source file not Code Behind>

Comment: what am I looking for there. I tried clicking on the event from property window it takes me straight to c# file of that event. So, I guess both source and code are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Finally had to give it up, and repeat everything. Hopefully had a back up of earlier version which was working. So, learned a lesson the hard way. Thanks everyone.